# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'watermark'

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Why is it Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'watermark' ?
Primefaces 3.2 JSF 2.1

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js"/>

<p:inputTextarea id="lessonRemarks" value="#{userController.selected.lessonRemarks}"/>
<p:watermark for="lessonRemarks" value="Search with a keyword" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you importing jQuery? Primefaces do that because it uses jQuery under the hood. With this your manual import you probably made some collision. So remove those two `h:outputScript` tags.

Comment: i include that because in my first implementation i was using jquery to manipulate my divs and now i change it so i forgot to remove it ... but thanks ...